# Trying to import a webstie template throught Django and keep getting this error

Tags: django, templates, mime

Every time I try and run the template I get this error:

Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Is there a place I can go to disable strict MIME checking?

Comment: How are your static files being served? It shouldn't be too hard to correctly configure whatever it is to send the correct mime type

Comment: My static files are being served through Django and I'm also using an index.html file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.